# I want to change the bool value on a database

Tags: c#, mysql, database

im creating a system that records if the room is open or not. the database wont update. every room is set to open when i created the database. (means at a certain time(row) a certain room(column) has a bool value which determines if it is open or not.) here is the code:

```
public void updateDatabase(int starttimestamp,int endtimestamp, string roomcode,string day,bool value)
        {
            string[] timeparam = new string[2];
            timeparam = configureTime(starttimestamp, endtimestamp, day);
            string param;
            param = convertInput(timeparam[0], timeparam[1], day);
            //dbc.executeSQLCommand("Update RoomTable set " + param + " = " + value+ " where (RoomCode = '"+ roomcode + "' )");
            string sqlcmd = "Update Roomtable set @param = @value where (Roomcode  = @roomcode)";
            using(SqlConnection sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(constr))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlcmd, sqlconnection))
            {
                sqlconnection.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("param", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = param;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("value",value);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("roomcode", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = roomcode;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlconnection.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: Is this Java? Tag your question appropriately

Comment: table schema? you're trying to set a variable there to another variable. that's not going to update your table

Comment: but how can i update a certain time if the time is paramater as well

Comment: set field = value[, field2 = value2, ... ], etc

Comment: what do you mean set field?

Comment: I am new here and if others could help me upon what i will do to make this question clear ans answerable ill be happy to do so

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
string sqlcmd = "Update Roomtable set @param = @value where (Roomcode  = @roomcode)";
```

You're trying to update `@param` which is not a column name, but a user variable.

Consider writing this:

```
string sqlcmd = "Update Roomtable set open = @value where (Roomcode  = @roomcode)";
```

where `open` is the column you want to update.

It's hard to say anything else without knowing the structure of your table.

Comment: my table has a primary key @roomcode with columns named like time phases like "A700800M" which means 7-8 on mondays. those timephases of course is user generated because the program lets the user see if a room is open at that time then update if the user wants to use that room at that time